# Detect If between time periods

Tags: ios, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm having issue with the code below. What's the issue with it? I have tried defining the `NSUInteger` as an `int`, but it still didn't work.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:nowNow];
NSLog(@"%ld",[components hour]);
NSUInteger *timeHour = [components hour];
if ( timeHour < 5 &&  timeHour > 9){}
```

This piece of code is supposed to detect wether it's between 5, and 9 in the morning.

Comment: What's the real issue? What do you want? Shouldn't the ">" & "<" reversed ?

Comment: You either want to use `||` instead of `&&` if your goal is to check for time before 5 or after 9. Or you want `timeHour > 5 && timeHour < 9` if you want to check for 6, 7, or 8.

Comment: || Still doesn't work

Comment: Tell us, in English, what you goal is here. What exactly are you trying to determine?

Comment: @SebOH That's because you're not being real clear on EXACTLY what sort of times should return `YES` and what sort of times should return `NO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by replacing the 'if' line with:

```
if ( [components hour] <= 5 && [components hour] >= 9){
```

and removing the `NSUInteger` line.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that returns true for `timeHour < 5` automatically will return false for `timeHour > 9`.  You're anding these two conditions, which can never both be true at the same time, so you'll always return a false.

Also, without anything in the `if` block, it's pretty impossible to tell whether or not it's executing.

You might be looking for something more like this:

```
if (timeHour >= 5 && timeHour <= 9) {
    // stuff
}
```

`timeHour >= 5` returns true for anything where `timeHour` is greater than or equal to 5.

`timeHour <= 9` returns true for anything where `timeHour` is less than or equal to 9.

`a && b` returns true only when both `a` and `b` are BOTH true.

---

EDIT: ALSO... `NSUInteger *timeHour = [components hour];`

There's a problem in this line I just caught.  You're defining `timeHour` as an `NSUInteger` POINTER, rather than an `NSUInteger`.  Get rid of the `*` and try again.

Comment: So how would I make it detect whether it's 5, and 9 in the morning using the NSDateComponents

Comment: Make the alligators face the other way.

Comment: @SebOH Please clarify. What do you mean by "it's 5, and 9"? Do you mean "between 5 and 9 (inclusive)", or "between 5 and 8 (exclusive)" or "either 5 or 9"?